# there's a Javascript/Ajax error message in Internet Explorer 8! by the way this is not the shocking part

Tags: javascript, ajax

```
function a (){
    var b = null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest) b = new XMLHttpRequest();
    else if(window.ActiveXObject) b = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    if(!b) b = new ActiveXObject("msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    return b;
}
var b=a();
function c(){
    var u = "ajax3_php.php?w="+ parseInt(Math.random()*88888);
    b.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if(b.status == 200 && b.readyState == 4){
            document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML = b.responseText;
        }
    }
    b.open("get", u, true);
    b.send();
}
```

And on the target page "ajax3_php.php":

```
&lt;?php
echo "OK";
?>
```

And on "divid" id
     <div id="divid">Test</div>

**the error message is:**

```
Message: Unspecified error.
Line: 20
Char: 3
Code: 0
URI: http://localhost/lat1/ajax/ajax3.php
```

The shocking part is, this is on line 20:

```
if(b.status == 200 && b.readyState == 4){
```

What is wrong with that? 

FYI : firebug says nothing.

Comment: My guess is that it's not that line that has the error.

Comment: @vijay : That is NOT the question

Comment: @Bagong: I agree. But using jquery, you don't have to worry about all these browser specific issues. It was just a suggestion.

Comment: eh, not even jQuery can save you from IE8.  those fangs are slick with the blood and tears of better developers than i.

Comment: Are you passing an HTML string or just some text (to the innerHTML call)? It's a simple fix to a problem I've seen before.

Comment: @Matt : No, just string, you can click edit on my question and see the whole code, it seems the <pre> tags don't work here, by the way what's the difference between HTML String and some text?

Comment: all IE error lines numbers are off by one. The actual error is on the next line. Most likely, document.getElementById("divid") doesn't exist.

Comment: @cwolves : it does, click edit on this question to see the whole code please, it seems the pre tags don't work in here

Comment: @Bagong21, an HTML string is HTML (intended for DOM insertion) encapsulated within a string, like `var str = '<strong>HTML Text</strong>";`. When referring to text, I mean "plain text", not something intended to be inserted as DOM element nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code seemed to do the trick.

```
function a()
{
    var b = null;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        b = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }else if(window.ActiveXObject)
    {
        b = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    if(!b)
    {
        b = new ActiveXObject("msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    return b;
}
var b = a();
function c()
{
    var u = "ajax3_php.php?w="+ parseInt(Math.random()*88888, 10);
    b.open("get", u, true);
    b.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(b.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(b.status === 200)
            {
                if(b.responseText)
                {
                    document.getElementById("divid").innerHTML = b.responseText;
                }
            }   
        }
    };
    b.send();
}

c();
```

I don't have a silver bullet answer as to why the error was popping up, but the call to `b.status` was throwing an error when the `readyState` wasn't `4`. However, that particular error was one I ran into recently (but a different error type) when sending an empty string via `innerHTML` to an element in IE 8 (I suspected your `responseText` was empty, causing the error).

I took the liberty of fixing that code for you (along with a few other touches). There are no errors in IE 7-8, Quirks or none.

I hope this helps you.

-Matt

EDIT: I stumbled upon this MSDN post. It's curious to see that their example code uses nested if blocks just like I did, yet no explanation. I'll investigate further.

Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd576252%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: I wrote my code (in my desktop+IE8) and there was an error then I tried it in my laptop (that has the same system specifications with my desktop) and it ran alright, that's weird. by the way, thanks for sharing your code, it's an elegant solution and also thanks for link to msdn.